# Pascal won't compile dynamic array of struct type

Tags: arrays, dynamic, struct, pascal, freepascal

I am programming in FreePascal and the task is to create a dynamic array of struct type. When I try to compile I get an error that says "[ expected but of found" . Since i am trying to create a dynamic array i do not need to use []. Here is a part of my program.

```
program duoemnys2;
uses crt, SysUtils;
const filee = 'failas.txt'     ;
type tipe = record
           firma: string;
           next,prev:integer;
           arpelnas: boolean;
           cash:real;
           miestas:char;
    end;

var kint : array of ^tipe;
    f:text;
    laikinas:string;
begin
  SetLength(kint, 5);
  Assign(f,filee);
  Readln;
end.
```

Help would be very appreciated

Comment: This code is compilabel with FPC 2.6.4 and 3.1.1

Comment: Are you sure you didn't strip too much of your original program away. Your code shown doesn't give the problem you mention here.

Comment: Yes, The above program can effectively get stripped to just "readln", since the rest is code that could be eliminated as assigning state that isn't used again.

Comment: I am programming in FPS 0.6.4a and tried to make program with and array of 5 for example , but as soon as I try to use dynamic one I get the same error.

Comment: FPS <> FPC, and current versions of FPC are in the 2.x and 3.x range, not 0.6. What specific Pascal are you using?

Comment: If it is FPS 0.6.4a it's probably [this one](http://ims.mii.lt/fps/en/about/index.html). Version FPS 0.6.4a comes with FPC 1.0.6 (from 2005). You might want to try the developers-version of FPS 0.9.6 from [here](http://ims.mii.lt/fps/en/devel/index.html). That one comes with FPC 2.1.1. Of course you could always go for [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/).